# Return a single string from multiple strings in a do block

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to achieve something similar to what is programmed in HaTeX, where a programmer would write LaTeX commands as text line by line. One of their examples is as follows:

```
-- Body with a section.
theBody :: Monad m => LaTeXT_ m
theBody = do
    maketitle
    section "Hello"
    "This is a simple example using the "
    hatex
    " library. "
    -- 'textbf' turns characters to bold font (as you already may know).
    textbf "Enjoy!"
    " "
```

Full example:
https://github.com/Daniel-Diaz/HaTeX/blob/master/Examples/simple.hs

So far I have achieved the following:

```
module Main 
where import System.IO


writeContent :: String 
writeContent = do
    "Some text. "
    ++ "Some more text. "
    ++ "This should all compile into a single line "
    ++ "and be output to the screen."

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr $ writeContent
```

But I'd really like to get rid of the `++` operators.

I'm aware that `Strings` and `++` are less efficient than `Text`, so will change that eventually once I learn a bit more. Am still quite new to Haskell. I've tried looking through HaTeX source code, but there are parts where too many steps are achieved in a single line, so wanted to build this up small steps at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [writer monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html):

```hs
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer

writeContent :: Writer String ()
writeContent = do
  tell "Some text. "
  tell "Some more text. "
  tell "This should all compile into a single line "
  tell "and be output to the screen."

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr $ execWriter writeContent
```

To do this without an extra (visible) function call like `tell`, you need the [`OverloadedStrings` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedStrings):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, OverloadedStrings
  #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Data.String

newtype StringBuilder a =
  StringBuilder (Writer String a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance (a ~ ()) => IsString (StringBuilder a) where
  fromString = StringBuilder . tell

buildString :: StringBuilder () -> String
buildString (StringBuilder w) = execWriter w

writeContent :: StringBuilder ()
writeContent = do
  "Some text. "
  "Some more text. "
  "This should all compile into a single line "
  "and be output to the screen."

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr $ buildString writeContent
```

Comment: In fact this is exactly what HaTeX does: its monad type is [a wrapper over WriterT](https://github.com/Daniel-Diaz/HaTeX/blob/5feee2f65c7d6ab45b097214fb3e43c0fc96588a/Text/LaTeX/Base/Writer.hs#L78). They of course also [must define IsString](https://github.com/Daniel-Diaz/HaTeX/blob/5feee2f65c7d6ab45b097214fb3e43c0fc96588a/Text/LaTeX/Base/Writer.hs#L215).